# Nodejs Mysql callbacks hell

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, callback

i have used async in nodejs with mysql to inject data from database .

so i cant pass data from mysql result to mysql end to print it out

see the this code it explians

```
    var users = [] ;

      .on('result', function(user,callback) {
    async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
        get_comm(user.post_id ,function(moredata){

            user.moredata = moredata;
            users.push(user);
            cb(users);

        })
    },

    ],function(users , cb){

    console.log(users); // it prints out successfully 
    });


})
.on('end', function() {
  if (connectionsArray.length) {
    pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
                console.log(users); // it prints out empty array [] !!

 updateSockets({
      users: users // empty array [] !!
    });


  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure waterfall is the best function for you, you could as well use each or eachSeries https://github.com/caolan/async, if you do have a bunch of user IDs.

Example:

```
userIDs = [1,3,42,23];
users = [];
async.each(users, function( user, callback) {
    get_comm(user,function(moredata){
      user.moredata = moredata;
      users.push(user);
      callback(users);
    })
  }
  }, function(err){
  if( err ) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(users);
  }
});
```

Try it out, I'm not sure this is what you want, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: i just want to know how to pass callback from async to another function

Comment: Replace console.log with your function

Answer (score 0):

```
 users =[] ;
.on('result', function(user) {
    async.waterfall([
    function(cb){get_comm(user.post_id , function(comms){

        user.comm = comms;
        users.push(user);
        cb(users);
    })
    },
    ],function(users ,cb){

        console.log(users); // it prints out
    });

})
.on('end', function() {
  if (connectionsArray.length) {
    pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
 updateSockets({
      users: users // empty []; !!

  });

  }
});
```

so iwant after finshing on result loop to print out all data but array is full in result  loop and empty out of it !!